# How to record test cases with robotframework?

Tags: selenium, testing, robotframework, gui-testing

I recently started using `robotframework` with the `Selenium2Library`. I haven't tested using *Selenium* before, but I know it is possible to record tests using *Selenium*. In `RobotFramework`, it says, *"it is not possible"*. I mean even for a simple login test, I need to *write the test*, specifying the id of username, password and submit button.

However, is there any way by which these tests can be recorded using `robotframework`? such as *clicking on a text box, entering a string and then clicking on submit button* etc., and automatically generate the test case source code instead of having me to write the test cases. 
Is this possible with `robotframework` or any `external library` that it supports?

Answer (score 2):

robotframework wasn't designed to be a record-and-play tool, and has nothing built-in to support that.

There was someone who wrote a selenium IDE plugin that would generate robot keywords, but that was years ago. The github repository is here: https://github.com/denschu/selenium-ide-format-robotframework

The code hasn't been touched since 2012, so I doubt it's of much use.

Comment: This should be a comment, really.

Comment: @GertArnold: why do you say that? The question is if it's possible, the correct answer is "no, it's not possible" ( or was at the time it was written). Why should "no" be a comment?

Comment: Because basically it's nothing but a link. And you even doubt its usefulness. Good for a comment, but not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using this Firefox add-on, [FireRobot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firerobot/?src=ss) we can generate most of the code and also using this you can select the elements on the screen and get related code suggestions on right click like
`Wait Until Element Is Visible`
`Click Element`
and all operations to perform on the selected element.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11004478)

Comment: The link which I provided is for downloading the addon because he was asking for a tool to do so, besides provided some info about the addon here in the page and improved the answer.

Comment: FireRobot is no longer under development. The author has migrated the project to the Chrome Browser and it is now called Chrome Robot. See here: https://github.com/joao-carloto/ChromeRobot