# Selenium with Robot

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am automating the GUI using `Robot framework` with `selinium2Library`. I am using selenium IDE and I don't find any record and play option for the Robot framework.

Is it possible for record and play back option for  the test cases with Robot framework using selenium2Libbrary instead of writing test cases manually?. Appreciate some early response on this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record test cases with robotframework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896990/how-to-record-test-cases-with-robotframework)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might got in confusion because of the work `selenium` which is different when you use it in `RobotFramework`.

I believe that you have to write the test cases, and you may `Pycharm IDE` where you get the context help for the in built as well for the user written keywords when the resources are imported.

However, I remember reading in a thread, but could not trace it. [Here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/02/recording-robot-framework-keywords-with-selenium-ide/) you can find article on how you can use `Selenium IDE` to record, but haven't tried myself. You may try it and see how it goes for you.

But I strongly believe that if you write the test, you can organize them into different reusable keywords than depending on the recording the stuff. Good luck.